# For Loops and If statements to move through an array relative to the first number >= 1

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array from a geotiff file. See the example array below:

```
example_array = [[ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                 [ 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0], 
                 [ 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0], 
                 [ 4, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0], 
                 [ 0, 5, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0], 
                 [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I am attempting to write a program that will change the values within the array based on their relative distance from the first number >=1 in each nested list.

The below code is able to change the first element >=1 in every list and add + 100 to the value.

```
for l in example_array:
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    if x > 1:
        l[i] += 100
        break
```

The below code is able to change the second element >=1 in every list and add + 100 to the value.

```
for l in example_array:
c = 0
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    if x >= 1:
        if c == 1:
            l[i] += 100
            break
        c += 1
```

I attempted to manipulate the above code such that I could manipulate the third element >= 1 in every list and add +100 to the value.

```
for l in example_array:
c1 = 0
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    if x >= 1:
        if c >= 1:
            if c1 == 1:
                l[i] += 100
                break
            c1 += 1
```

The thought process here is that if I continue to increase the `if statements`to check the value of the element at each location away from the first element >=1 it would continue to move through the array. The addition of `if c1 ==1:` does nothing to change the values within the array at the third location away from the first element >= 1.

Comment: Your code has indentation issues. It is not valid.

Comment: In the last code block you have an undefined variable `c`. If we assume it should be `c1` , then the `if c1 >= 1:` condition will never be true. Again an indentation issue with `c1 += 1`

Comment: When talking about distance from first element are you talking about each list inside the main list or  the main list itself?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Check for `c` (the counter variable) being `2` instead. There is no need for another `if` statement.

```py
if x >= 1:
    if c == 2: # third one
        l[i] += 100
        break
    c += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
example_array = [[ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                 [ 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0], 
                 [ 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0], 
                 [ 4, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0], 
                 [ 0, 5, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0], 
                 [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

cond = 1


for l in example_array:
    c = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        if x >= 1:
            if c == cond:
                l[i] += 100
                break
            c += 1

print(example_array)
```

The above code should be able to change the 3rd variable>=1.

Issues with original code:-

- Written c instead of c1
- Indentation issue (python is tab sensitive)

You can change the cond variable for printing the nth variable